# Tuleap LDAP Subversion Browse Svn Tree Issue

Tags: python, svn, ldap, tuleap

I have enabled LDAP on tuleap. But when I go to subversion> Browse SVN tree, I get following error

An Exception Has Occurred

Python Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
   "/usr/share/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py", line 3814, in main
       request.run_viewvc()   File "/usr/share/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py", line 318, in run_viewvc
       if not svnaccess.check_read_access(user.user_getname(), self.rootpath, self.where):   File
   "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/svnaccess.py", line 130, in
   check_read_access
       username = get_name_for_svn_access(svnrepo, username)   File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/svnaccess.py", line 119, in
   get_name_for_svn_access
       return codendildap.get_login_from_username(username)   File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/codendildap.py", line 60, in
   get_login_from_username
       return get_login_from_eduid(row['ldap_id'])   File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/codendildap.py", line 43, in
   get_login_from_eduid
       l = ldap_connect()   File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/svn/codendildap.py", line 33, in
   ldap_connect
       l = ldap.initialize(server)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 85, in
   initialize
       return LDAPObject(uri,trace_level,trace_file,trace_stack_limit)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line
   69, in __init__
       self._l = ldap.functions._ldap_function_call(_ldap.initialize,uri)   File
   "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 57, in
   _ldap_function_call
       result = func(*args,**kwargs) LDAPError:(0, 'Error')
```

$sys_ldap_server = 'X.X.X.X:xxx'; $sys_ldap_cn='cn'; $sys_ldap_people_dn='ou=Users,dc=xxxx,dc=org'; $sys_ldap_search_user='(|(uid=%words%)(cn=%words%))'; $sys_ldap_default_user_status='A'; $sys_ldap_svn_auth=1; $sys_ldap_daily_sync=1; $sys_ldap_user_management=1; $sys_ldap_grp_enabled = 1; $sys_ldap_grp_dn='ou=groups,dc=xxxx,dc=org'; $sys_ldap_grp_cn = 'cn'; $sys_ldap_grp_member='uniquemember';

Comment: Can you add the ldap config (/etc/tuleap/conf/plugins/ldap/etc/ldap.inc) ? (be careful with the passwords)

Comment: I have added ldap.inc code without comment tag.

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP server configuration variable should be defined with ldap:// (or ldaps:// for SSL LDAP)